# Runtime error while getting the last empty cell

Tags: vba

I am getting the below run time error when going to the last empty cell.
Please note: in the A column i do have empty cells in between

> Run-Time error '1004'

Below is the code

```
 Set MainWb = ThisWorkbook 
 Set DestWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Test_Data.xls") 

 Msgbox DestWb.Sheets("EMT").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'error at this line
 For c = 1 to DestWb.Sheets("EMT").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'Mycode
 Next c
```

> Sheets("EMT") does exsist as well as that DestWb is saved in the macro saved workbook

Am i missing something overhere. Is there any alternative?

Comment: Rows.count for xls file (65536) and xlsx file (1048576). It should be `DestWb.Sheets("EMT").Range("A" & DestWb.Sheets("EMT").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1` to avoid error due to references to different versions of Excel.

Comment: put in `msgbox Rows.Count` just to see the value

Comment: this code worked for me - thinking that your particular sheet name is not able to map

Comment: Thanks for the update. Below code worked for me.  `DestWb.Sheets(Shname1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row`